# Combining multiple rows into one using precedence rules

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres, I have a list of records in my table that I know are duplicates. Given this list of duplicates 
(`id IN (1,2,3,4)`), I want to combine them into a single record using the following precedence rules (from highest precedence to lowest):

- Non-NULL values
- Values of records with `force=true`
- Records with the latest `updated` value

For example:

[image]

Should turn into this:

[image]

[Fiddle with schema here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed8fe/4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
select distinct
       first_value(col1) filter (where col1 is not null) over (order by force desc, updated desc) as col1,
       first_value(col2) filter (where col2 is not null) over (order by force desc, updated desc) as col2,
       first_value(col3) filter (where col3 is not null) over (order by force desc, updated desc) as col3,
       first_value(col4) filter (where col4 is not null) over (order by force desc, updated desc) as col4
from t
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I'm not a bit fan of `select distinct` with window functions, but Postgres doesn't (yet) offer `first_value()` as an aggregation function.

You can do something similar using `array_agg()` as well.

EDIT:

I didn't realize that `filter` doesn't work with `first_value()`.  Arrggh.  The `array_agg()` form is:

```
select (array_agg(column1 order by force desc, updated desc) filter (where column1 is not null))[1] as column1,
       (array_agg(column2 order by force desc, updated desc) filter (where column2 is not null))[1] as column2,
       (array_agg(column3 order by force desc, updated desc) filter (where column3 is not null))[1] as column3      
from test_table;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed8fe/28) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it says 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "column1" Position: 53' http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed8fe/11

Comment: @Meow . . . Arrgh.  I fixed the syntax error, but `filter` doesn't work with `first_value()`.  Thanks for setting up the SQL Fiddle.  The `array_agg()` version really does work.